# How to implement process bar when insert 1000record at a time

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0

I need to display process bar when i press add button and 1000 static data is insert into database.

e.g. I write "sangeet" into textbox and when i press submit at the time this sangeet word is insert into database using c# code 1000 time insert. insertation take much time to insert so i need to display process bar at front site when insertation into progress. how many time word is insert.

code:-

```
public void add()
{

  for(i=0;i<=1000;i++)
  {
       insert("sangeet"); // insert method that insert this word into database
  }

}
```

how can i do it?

Comment: Show your code. How do you insert your data into database? Do you use ORM? Show the loop when you insert data 1000 times.

Comment: Start the insert method in a task, then make variable (count/total)*100 and set that variable to a progress bar.

Comment: but how this variable display at website page at the time of of inseration.

Comment: Insert all those in one transaction. You don't need a progress bar

Comment: but i need to check progress that how much done

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28613630/how-do-i-refresh-a-partial-view-every-3-seconds-in-mvc-4

Comment: @vinayakhegde hedge. anothe process is going to queue when one request is not complete. so this is not work for me

Answer (score 0):

for server side progress
`int progress = limit/i`  where limit =1000 and i is your for loop variable

for client side progress (used for progress bar)
Run the code with a for loop in java-script and let the java-script method do a server call to insert into the database. then use 
then use [Using progress bar in asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11754477/using-progress-bar-in-asp-net)

Comment: this is not helpfull for me